# is PHP fast enough to transmit heavy data traffic?

Tags: php

i'm developing a chat program in PHP where more than 500 users to be connected per day. plus it would own file transfer function as well thus the program must be fast enough. so i wanna know if the PHP is fast enough to accomplish this job or i must use other one platform??

Comment: The pure language speed in not really the problem. *How* you're doing it is.

Comment: 500 users per DAY? It's nothing!!! "Basic" from 1995 can do it.

Comment: @Emmerman: I assume he means that there will be 500 simultaneous users. Not that much still, but for PHP over Long Polling it may already be quite problematic.

Comment: @nikic I had about 5k simultaneous users on my server - no problems with this.

Comment: @Emmerman: No 5k aren't a problem ^^ Just if all those 5k need there own PHP process all the time (like when implementing a chat), *then* you'll have problems.

Comment: @nikic My server has a chat with a long polling :)

Comment: @Emmerman: Interesting, that's interesting. Are you using that phpDaemon you posted as a comment to my answer or just "normal" PHP. If the latter, that would be really surprising.

Comment: @nikic Daemon of course. But.. it's still php right? :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PHP is fast enough. The only variable here is your coding skill (and if the number of users really gets out of hand, your server configuration) - if you make the chat program well, there shouldn't be any problems.

It is imperative you give your tables good indices, and that you optimize your queries. When done properly, a PHP chat can support thousands of concurrent users with almost no impact on performance.

Comment: -1 I disagree. PHP will have problems handling many concurrent connections. That's no problem for normal applications, because you just don't have that many concurrent connections, but for a chat, where every user must have one connection open to the server all the time, it is a problem.

Comment: I recently made one such chat for my company's CRM, and it works well. It's heartbeat based, and looks for changes every 2 seconds. We currently have an average load of 3000 users per day, up to 1000 of those at the same time. There is no general performance degradation. I can't say what would happen with 10 times as many users, but right now it works flawlessly.

Comment: Hm, okay, I redrew my downvote. You and Emmerman convinced me that it is indeed possible to build a long polling chat in PHP. Though I still like the nodejs solution more...